# Image size getting reduced

Tags: java, image, graphics2d

Below is a small code which takes input of File containing image and then tilts it by an angle. Now the problem is that: the output file has a lower resolution when compared to the input one. In my case input file was of size 5.5 MB and the output file was of 1.1 MB.
Why is it?

```
/**
 * 
 * @param angle Angle to be rotate clockwise. Ex: Math.PI/2, -Math.PI/4
 */
private static void TurnImageByAngle(File image, double angle)
{
    BufferedImage original = null;
    try {
        original = ImageIO.read(image);        
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
        BufferedImage rotated1 = tilt(original, angle, gc);        
        //write iamge
        ImageIO.write(rotated1, getFileExtension(image.getName()), new File("temp"+" "+angle+"."+getFileExtension(image.getName())));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RotateImage2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static GraphicsConfiguration getDefaultConfiguration() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    return gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
}

public static BufferedImage tilt(BufferedImage image, double angle, GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
    int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
    int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin), newh = (int)Math.floor(h*cos+w*sin);
    int transparency = image.getColorModel().getTransparency();
    BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh, transparency);
    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
    g.translate((neww-w)/2, (newh-h)/2);
    g.rotate(angle, w/2, h/2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is the File a JPEG?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Image can be either an JPEG, JPG< PNG, Tiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats no surprise if you look at the code (Copy&Paste without understanding what the Code does *has* its drawbacks). The tilt()-Method makes extra effort (in its 3rd line) to make the image properly sized.

If you think about it, you *cant* expect the image to stay the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, the resulting image may not have the same color model as the original

```
gc.createCompatibleImage(...)
```

Is creating a BufferedImage whose color model is compatible with device that the GraphicsConfiguration is associated.  This may potentially reduce the size of the image.

ImageIO may also be also be applying a different compression algorithm from the original

Comment: For JPEG, yes.  I did not know ImageIO supported TIFF (without JAI being installed).

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't, most likely the OP hasn't got that far yet :)